# Submitting a string to the JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts

I'm trying to load some text onto a JSP page. I really don't know how to do that. I'm using Struts2 so I can use its tags.

This is the only line in the body:

```
<s:property value="myTextToAdd" />
```

I know this isn't much to go on but I don't know what to ask at the moment. I just want to be able to call a java class and have it return the text I want to the JSP page.

Comment: You should read the manual. BTW, you need a mapping in struts.xml that define which Action returns which JSP as result. Then define the private property you want in the Action, add Getter and Setter, and the line you already have in the JSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some simple tutorial for struts 2 [Struts 2 Hello World](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-struts-2-application-eclipse-example/) it will get you basic startup introduction. Try this may be you will get some idea about struts2

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you use the Action -> JSP flow. That allows to prepare/render JSP for the browser response, so it will already have the data populated via the Struts tags like a `property` tag. In the action class you make a property that you want to print out via `property` tag.

```
 private String myTextToAdd;

 //getter
 public String getMyTextToAdd(){
   return myTextToAdd;
 }
 //setter you need if you want to submit it, could be here
```

Then in the action you should do something like

```
 public String execute(){

   myTextToAdd = "Some text to out";
   ...
   return SUCCESS;
 }
```

The SUCCESS result should return a `dispatcher` result type, which is default. You have also configure the action to map some URL and result to it. Then you can use a `property` tag to out the value.

Se the detailed explanation from the Struts2 [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-property-tag-example/).